# Changing the color of of a PNG file converted to SVG in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, png

Just got done converting a png Photoshop file to a SVG in Illustrator but I"m not able to change the color to the the deired dcolor. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Illustrator’s Live Trace**

1.Click on the `selection tool` (the black arrow) in the top of the left tool bar and then click on your image to select it. You know it is selected when there is a blue box around your image.

[image]

2.Click on the small down arrow button next to `Live Trace`. See the red arrow in the picture above.

3.Click on `Photo High Fidelity`

4.You will then need to hit the `Expand button or Object -> Live Trace -> Expand` to see the actual results.

5.Be sure to `Ungroup (Shift + Cmd/Ctrl + G) (Object > Ungroup)` as many times as necessary to make sure everything is ungrouped.

**RECOLOR ARTWORK**

Great for playing with color combinations. This feature takes the existing colors and provides complimentary color options which can be viewed instantly. To open the palette, select your artwork and click the little colorful circular button on the top menu, or choose `Edit > Edit Colors >Recolor Artwork`.  This is pretty intuitive to use.